# functions and input for a deck of cards

Tags: python, function

I was writing a program that would take input for a custom number of suits and values for a deck of cards. These could be enumerated and named, the lists would be merged (two + of + clubs, or whatever) and then the deck could be shuffled.

I was getting along fine with while loops, but in learning functions I feel like I'm missing some logic. The problem is, the code works. I just thought it would work for a different reason than it does.

For example, in do_the_stuff(), I ask it to print a message and then run a series of functions that assemble the deck. It does both of those things but in the opposite order.

I noticed that if I remove the call for the functions with INPUT inside them, they run anyway, which I did not expect. If they are running anyway, and first, how do they hold the information until called later by the other function that assembles it?

Here is the code:

```
import random

def suit_generator():
   
    a = int(input("How many suits in this deck: "))
    suits = []
    
    for i in range(a):
        new_suit = input(f"Name suit No. {i+1} - ")
        suits.append(new_suit)
    
    return suits


def value_generator():
   
    a = int(input("How many values for each suit: "))
    values = []
    
    for i in range(a):
        new_value = input(f"Name value No. {i+1} - ")
        values.append(new_value)

    return values


def merge_suits_and_values(s = suit_generator(), v = value_generator()):
  
    deck = []
    suit_counter = 0
    
    for i in s:
        
        value_counter = 0
        for x in v:
            new_card = f"the {v[value_counter]} of {s[suit_counter]}"
            deck.append(new_card)
            value_counter += 1
        
        suit_counter += 1

    return deck

def display_deck():
    
    deck = merge_suits_and_values()
    counter = 0
    for i in deck:
        print(f"{counter + 1} {deck[counter]}")
        counter += 1

def shuffle_deck():

    deck = merge_suits_and_values()
    random.shuffle(deck)
    counter = 0
    for i in deck: 
        print(f"{counter + 1} - {deck[counter]}")
        input()
        counter += 1

def do_the_stuff():
    
    print("Let's create and then shuffle a custom deck of cards.")
    display_deck()
    print("This is the shuffled deck, dealing one card at a time:")
    input()
    shuffle_deck()

do_the_stuff()
```

Comment: When you provide default parameters, those statements are evaluated at the time the function is defined, **not** every time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the functions to create the input where you define the `merge_suits_and_values` it will evaluate those function while defining `merge_suits_and_values`. This should work.

```
def merge_suits_and_values(s, v) #when defining

merge_code_suits_and_values(suit_generator(), value_generator) #when calling
```